# Where to place a charge to establish net force of 0?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, charge

A charge, Q2 = -15.00x10^-6 C, is 10.00 cm to the right of charge Q1 = 18.00x10^-6 C. Where can a third charge be placed, along the line connecting Q1 and Q2, such that it experiences no net force (other than ±∞)?
Give distances relative to Q1 and use a plus sign if the third charge is to the right of Q1 (and negative sign if the charge is to the left).

I have tried using both main charge equations as well as even f=ma (which clearly would' even work in this scenario) Somebody please help me!

Comment: Draw a coordinate axis with coordinates (i.e, 1 cm, 2 cm, 3 cm ...) and place the charges where they belong.  Of course, one will have an unknown coordinate.  Calculate the force on that charge.  Pay close attention to all of the signs.